# How to exit from postgres' single-user mode?

Tags: postgresql, single-user

I have entered postgres' single-user mode

```
$ sudo -u postgres postgres --single -D /var/db/postgresql/

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.4.11
backend>
```

What command can I use to close single-user mode and exit back to a normal `$` command prompt?

---

The command `\q` works to exit from the `psql` repl, but that same command does not appear to work for postgres single-user mode, i.e.

```
$ sudo -u postgres postgres --single -D /var/db/postgresql/

PostgreSQL stand-alone backend 9.4.11
backend> \q
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\" at character 1
STATEMENT:  \q

backend>
```

Comment: Should be just `\q`

Comment: @JorgeCampos Unlike `psql` utility, `\q` does not appear to work in this case; question edited to show that.

Comment: Ok, let me retract that vote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is on the Postgresql Docs page at [Single-User mode](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-postgres.html#APP-POSTGRES-SINGLE-USER). Regarding the exit it states:

> To quit the session, type EOF (**Control+D**, usually). If you've entered any text since the last command entry terminator, then EOF will be taken as a command entry terminator, and another EOF will be needed to exit.